# Blur toolbar background on Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose there is the `Modifier.blur()` method.
But it blurs the content of the container it's applied on.

I have a similar structure like this:

```
Box {
    Toolbar()
    Content()
}
```

The Toolbar is above the Content in the z-axis. I want to give Toolbar some opacity and Blur everything from the Content that is behind the Toolbar.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Composable
fun BlurredBackground() {
    Box {
        Content()
        
        // blur effect
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .zIndex(1f)
        ) {
            BackdropFilter(
                filter = ImageFilter.blur(10f), // adjust the blur
                content = { }
            )
        }
        
        Toolbar(Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.7f)) // adjust the opacity
            .zIndex(2f)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try it out soon, thanks for now!

Comment: There's no such thing as `BackdropFilter` in Compose, it exists in Flutter only.